# How to add a new exception handler to Laravel without disable the default one?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, sentry

I'm using [Sentry](https://getsentry.com/) to keep tracking of exceptions from a Laravel application.

Sentry's docs say I should use the following code in my application bootstrap to setup the client:

```
$app->configureMonologUsing(function($monolog) {
    $client = new Raven_Client('your dsn');
    $handler = new Monolog\Handler\RavenHandler($client);
    $handler->setFormatter(new Monolog\Formatter\LineFormatter("%message% %context% %extra%\n"));
    $monolog->pushHandler($handler);
});
```

And that works fine!

The side effect is that Laravel's default exception handler, which writes the exceptions to the file at `/storage/logs/laravel.log`, stopped to work after adding the new exception handler.

How can I keep both handlers?

**UPDATE for Laravel 5.6+**

Starting on Laravel 5.6 log stacks are available. It now allows devs to set up multiple log channels with ease. Refer to [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/logging) for more info on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at `Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\ConfigureLogging` to see how Laravel sets up its native logging. Then in your own bootstrap, just push another handler that does the same:

```
$app->configureMonologUsing(function($monolog) {

    // Keep your existing Sentry configuration
    $client = new Raven_Client('your dsn');
    $handler = new Monolog\Handler\RavenHandler($client);
    $handler->setFormatter(new Monolog\Formatter\LineFormatter("%message% %context% %extra%\n"));
    $monolog->pushHandler($handler);

    // Add another handler that writes to laravel.log
    $handler = new Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler(storage_path('logs/laravel.log'));
    $handler->setFormatter(new Monolog\Formatter\LineFormatter(null, null, true, true));
    $monolog->pushHandler($handler);

});
```

**Edit:**

If you don't need to reproduce Laravel's behaviour *exactly*, you could use the default formatter for a one-liner addition instead:

```
$monolog->pushHandler(new Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler(storage_path('logs/laravel.log')));
```

This differs from the native Laravel implementation in that it'll use the  [default constructor arguments](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/master/src/Monolog/Formatter/LineFormatter.php#L37) for `LineFormatter` rather than those we were setting explicitly before.

A third option that reuses Laravel's logic for configuring Monolog would be the addition of this line instead:

```
with(new Illuminate\Log\Writer($monolog))->useFiles(storage_path('logs/laravel.log'));
```

Comment: I'm looking here https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/ConfigureLogging.php, but I don't see a `StreamHandler` instance there.

Comment: `StreamHandler` is imported from the Monolog package, source is at: https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/master/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php ... but you shouldn't need to dive any deeper than `Illuminate\Log\Writer` to reproduce the Laravel behaviour. The code in answer should work.

Comment: I was expecting something more concise. Maybe the framework should have a way to keep the default logger. But not your fault, your code worked. Thank you!

Comment: No probs, I've added a couple of alternative ways to achieve the same result which are more concise, if that's any help. Personally I'd stick with the original answer - although more verbose, it avoids mixing levels of abstraction that could be confusing. But doesn't much matter, whatever best suits your needs!